# My Google Kubernetes Cluster is down, how can I recover?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

My Google Kubernetes is down and the only message I see on the dashboard is "The cluster has a problem."

When I execute

```
gcloud container clusters describe [cluster-name]
```

The second to last line shows "status: ERROR""

The cluster node pool is up and running.

Any idea how I can recover this cluster?

Comment: Consider adding logging to your application https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/, or just look at the cluster logs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, the billing account was suspended "for failure to pay past due amounts or invalid payment information".  The linked credit card was still valid and after refreshing the payment method the cluster become active again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if all nodes are all registered correctly
   **kubectl get nodes**
2. Verify in the **ready** section that all of the nodes you expect to see are present.
3. Looking at logs:
   Check the relevant log files
   Note that in system-based you need to use **journalct1** instead
   #Master
   #workerNodes
   #rootCauses
   #mitigation

Comment: "kubectl get nodes" shows that the nodes are in "NotReady" status.